# What does represent the number inside the brackets in "aTargets"?

Tags: datatables

In this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table_tabl').attr('style', 'width:100%');
            $('#table_tabl').dataTable({
                responsive: true,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl": "<?php  echo RP_LANG ?>fr_FR.txt",
                },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                ajax: "<?php  echo RP_SSP ?>server_processing_reservTables.php",  
                "aoColumnDefs": 
                    [{ 
                        "aTargets": [5],
                        "mData": 4,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) { 
                        var table_ = '\''+full [0]+'\'';
                        return '<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="Restaurantreservation/modifierReservTable/'+ data +'"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>'+ 
                           '<a href="#" id="staticDialog" onclick="afficheDlg('+ data +','+table_+')" style="color:red;font-size:14px;" title="Supprimer"><i class="icon-cancel-2"></i></a>'+
                           '<a href="Restaurantreservation/affecterReservTable/'+ data +'"><i class="icon-locked"></i></a>'+
                           '<a href="Restaurantreservation/annulerReservTable/'+ data +'"><i class="icon-unlocked"></i></a></div>';
                         },
                    }],
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25,50,100, -1], [10, 25,50,100, "Tout"]]
            });
});
```

What does represent the number inside the brackets in the `aTargets` option ( inside the `aoColumnDefs` option ) ?

Comment: It's your code, *you* tell *us* what the `5` stands for. Or perhaps did you intend to give us more background info and relevant tags?

Comment: I put a test value , but I dont understand its meaning !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aTargets` property is an array to target one of many columns and each element in it can be:

- a string - class name will be matched on the TH for the column
- 0 or a positive integer - column index counting from the left
- a negative integer - column index counting from the right
- the string "_all" - all columns (i.e. assign a default)

More [Details](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Comment: what do you mean by `target` when you said `an array to target one of many columns` ?

Comment: `target` means targeting specific column.